# Unable to locate package dh_python while executing apt-get install

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am trying to build diamond(monitoring source) through make.

The command i execute is: make builddeb

but it is failing due to missing dependency:

I tried both apt-get and pip, but no luck. How can i install dh-python? if dh-python not possible then is there any other way i can build source and generate debian package?

Error stack:

```
root@vivektestdev:/usr/local/share/diamond_src# apt-get install dh_python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dh_python
root@vivektestdev:/usr/local/share/diamond_src# pip install dh_python
Downloading/unpacking dh-python
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement dh-python
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for dh-python
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
root@vivektestdev:/usr/local/share/diamond_src# less /root/.pip/pip.log 
root@vivektestdev:/usr/local/share/diamond_src#
```

root@vivektestdev:/opt# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
root@vivektestdev:/opt#

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try: 
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get install -f && apt-get install dh-python ; still not working?

Comment: Hey, I tried above commands. Its still giving me

root@vivektestdev:~# apt-get install dh-python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dh-python
root@vivektestdev:~#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This solution is very risky to use it for real business purpose. as the package is built for a sausy system. Use it at your own risk.

so i found an alternative solution on ubuntu package site.

Here are the steps:

1) go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/all/dh-python/download

2) edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add link mentioned in above link.

So for my case, I added:

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu saucy main in /etc/apt/sources.list

then run apt-get install dh-python

Thank you guys for all the help. If anyone else have other good solution then please do post up.

Answer (score 0):

The Debian package appears to be called `dh-python`, not `dh_python`.

Comment: Yeah, I dd realized that I accidently typed wrong name. But even with correct name "dh-python", its still giving me same error.

Answer (score 0):

Which Debian version are you running (Stable/Testing/Unstable)? If you are not sure, please post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list so we can figure out.

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dh-python shows that there are three versions of dh-python depending on the debian version you are running. If possible, I would like to narrow down the problematic version.

Comment: I understand you can't comment to get clarification, so better you update your answer with some assumption and if you can't, delete this post.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my initial post with debian version. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Thanks. I am more familiar with Debian and am not sure what could be the cause of problem if you are using Ubuntu. Are you sure there is a dh_python package available in your repositories? What does "apt-cache search dh_python" give you? If not you might have to get the source from Debian and compile it.

Comment: Sakura, I can't make an assumption and provide an answer without knowing the specifics. If you go to a doctor and do not explain the symptoms correctly, do you expect him to say "I am assuming you have cancer... here, take this medicine?". That said, if you feel like I am violating some kind of policy, please delete my post yourself.